# Encapsulate multiple types of exceptions in a TypeInitializationException

Tags: c#, exception

I'm triying to manage the various types of exceptions thrown when instantiating a type by encapsulating them in a TypeInitializationException. To avoid repeating code, I have this in my factory:

```
try
{
    CheckFields(field1, field2...);
}
catch (Exception ex) when (ex is ArgumentException || ex is ArgumentNullException || ex is ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
{
    throw new TypeInitializationException("MyType", ex);
}

....

private void CheckFields(string field1, string field...)
{
    if (field1== null) throw new ArgumentNullException("field1", "field1 can't be null");
    if (field1.Trim().Length==0) throw new ArgumentException("field1 can't be empty", "field1");
    if (field1.Trim().Length > 35) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("field1", "field1 can't be longer than 35 characters");
    if (field2== null) throw new ArgumentNullException("field2", "field2 can't be null");
    if (field2.Trim().Length == 0) throw new ArgumentException("field2 can't be empty", "field2");
    if (field2.Trim().Length > 35) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("field2", "field2 can't be longer than 35 characters");
    ....
}
```

When catching the TypeInitializationException later, I just need to read the inner exception.

My problem is that the inner exception is encapsulated as an Exception, not as a
ArgumentException, ArgumentNullException or an ArgumentOutOfRangeException. I can 'GetType()' later the InnerException it to see whats is the real type, and cast it, but I would like throw with the original type of exception. My only solution till now has been:

```
catch (Exception ex) when (ex is ArgumentException || ex is ArgumentNullException || ex is ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
{
    if (ex is ArgumentException)  throw new TypeInitializationException("MyType", (ArgumentException)ex);
    if (ex is ArgumentNullException) throw new TypeInitializationException("MyType", (ArgumentNullException)ex);
    if (ex is ArgumentOutOfRangeException) throw new TypeInitializationException("MyType", (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)ex);
}
```

Is there an easier/more elegant way to do it?

Comment: This is a bit strange, could you clarify why you need to cast inner exception back to the original type?

Comment: To me, the easier and more elegant way to do it is not to wrap the real exception in a TypeInitializationException. What is having the wrapper gaining you, since you still have to peel apart the `InnerException` to find out what really happened?

Comment: @S. I thought it could be a more structured way to manage the exceptions caused during type initialization, and easier to read by the upper levels (Clean Code): _"the exception was caused during a type initialization... why... look inner exception type"_. My first code for throwing exceptions was like this:`if (field1 == null) throw new TypeInitializationException("MyType", new ArgumentNullException("field1", "Field1 can't be null"));` May be i'm making things more complicated than needed? I tend to do that... I'll follow your advice :)

Comment: If you can roll the exception up and handle it categorically, then it is worth creating the `TypeInitializationException`. However, if the handler has to process the `InnerException`, then much of the value has been lost. Can you provide sufficient info in the `TypeInitializationException` and its message (and possibly other properties) so that the recipient does not have to look at the `InnerException` at all?

Comment: Thanks for your comments :)